# Is there an integer $y>0$ such that for all $x>y$, at least $4$ of $x+1, x+2, x+3, x+4, x+5$ are divisible by a prime greater than $5$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

As I understand it, the answer to this question is yes.

I would appreciate it if anyone could provide a counter example or provide details on how to resolve this question.

My thinking is that this is true for $y > 80$

Here's my thinking:

1. We can assume that there is at least on integer in the sequence $x+i$ such that $x+i = 2^a3^b5^c$ where $a,b,c \ge 0$ and $a+b+c > 0$ and $1 \le i \le 5$
2. So, I am trying to prove that there is no solution for $x>24$ where $2^a3^b5^c + d = 2^e3^f5^g$ and $1 \le d \le 5$
3. Let $f=gcd(2^a3^b5^c,2^e3^f5^g)$ and we need only deal with the following forms:

**Case 1:  $2^a \pm 1 = 3^b5^c$ where $a,b,c > 0$**

- Since $a > 1$, we know that $b$ is even since $(-1)^b(1) \equiv \pmod 4$
- Since $a > 2$, we know that $c$ is even since $(1)^{\frac{b}{2}}(-3)^c \equiv 1 \pmod 8$
- But then $(3^{\frac{b}{2}}5^{\frac{c}{2}} + 1)(3^{\frac{b}{2}}5^{\frac{c}{2}} - 1)  = 2^a$ which is impossible for $a > 1$
- Let's look at $2^a-1 = 3^b5^c$
- There is no solution for $a$ is even because $(2^{\frac{a}{2}} - 1)(2^{\frac{a}{2}} + 1)= 3^b5^c$ which is impossible since $b,c > 1$
- There is no solution for $a$ is odd because $(-1)^a - 1 \not\equiv 0 \pmod 3$

**Case 2:  $3^a \pm 1 = 2^b5^c$ where $a,b,c > 0$**

- Let's start $3^a+1 = 2^b5^c$
- $a$ cannot be odd because only $(-2)^{4x+2} + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$
- $a$ cannot be even since $(-1)^a + 1 \not\equiv 0 \pmod {10}$
- Let's look at $3^a - 1 = 2^b5^c$
- $a$ cannot be even since $(3^{\frac{a}{2}}-1)(3^{\frac{a}{2}}+1) = 2^b5^c$ is impossible for $b > 5,c>0$ or for $b >0,c>1$
- $a$ cannot be odd since only $(-2)^(4x) - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$

**Case 3:  $5^a \pm 1 = 2^b3^c$ where $a,b,c > 0$**

- Let's look at $5^a + 1 = 2^b3^c$
- We know if there's a solution that $b=1$ since $(1)^a + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod 4$
- Since $c>1$, it follows that $a=6k+3$ since $5^a \equiv -1 \pmod 9$
- $5^{6k+3}+1\equiv 0 \pmod 7$
- But $2^b3^c \not\equiv 0 \pmod 7$
- Let's look at $5^a-1 = 2^b3^c$
- $a$ cannot be even since $(5^{\frac{a}{2}}-1)(5^{\frac{a}{2}}+1) = 2^b3^c$ is impossible for $b>1,c> 0$
- $a$ cannot be odd since $(-1)^a-1 \not\equiv 0 \pmod 6$

**Case 4:  $2^a \pm 1 = 3^b$ where $a,b > 0$**

**Case 5:  $2^a \pm 1 = 5^b$ where $a,b > 0$**

**Case 6:  $3^a \pm 1 = 5^b$ where $a,b > 0$**

Case 4,5, and 6 are impossible for $x > 24$ by the proof behind Catalan's conjecture.

---

Edit: Eric Towers has pointed out that $\{80,81\}$ do not have a prime greater than $5$.  It seems that my logic in Case 2 did not account for $(3^2 - 1)(3^2 + 1) = 2^4*5$

I've updated my assumption to $y > 80$.  This removes the counter example.  I will spend time reading up on smooth numbers and spending time verifying that $80$ is the correct value for $y$.  If anyone has a precise formulation, that will be greatly appreciated.  :-)

Comment: Regarding your thought 1:  $\{91,92,93,94,95\}$ doesn't contain a number that completely factors over $2,3,5$.  (Large factors are 13, 23, 31, 47, and 19, respectively.) ... or do I misunderstand what you're trying to say with thought 1?

Comment: Hi Eric, I meant that at least 4 of the numbers will be divisible by a prime greater than $5$.  In your example, $7 \mid 91$, $23 \mid 92$, $31 \mid 93$ and $47 \mid 94$.  I hope that clarifies what I am looking for.

Comment: Then perhaps 80 and 81 being 5-smooth is a counterexample?  (Any 5 consecutive integers containing them has at most three elements divisible by a prime > 5.)

Comment: Great!  Thanks very much!  I'll read up on what "5-smooth means".  That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: 160,161,162,163,164 would be a counter example where I could take the {80,81} and multiply each by 2 and pick 5 consecutive integers with 160 and 162. Note that I could also take 240,241,242,243,244 for another case using 3 as the multiple to get 240 and 243. Multiplying by 4 yields 320,321,322,323,324 which would be a relatively large counter example at the moment.

Comment: Hi JB, you are absolutely right.  My calculations are incorrect.  I  will update my numbers above as soon as I have reviewed all the counter examples and have a new estimate for $y$.

Comment: You may wish to read about Stormer's theorem for hints on methods of proof for (some) problems of this type.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%B8rmer%27s_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr:  If $x+1 \geq 321$, then the five consecutive integers starting at $x+1$ have at most one 5-smooth member.

It is sufficient to ask how often 5-smooth numbers are nearby.  If there are a pair of 5-smooth numbers with difference < 5, then no consecutive 5 integers containing the pair can satisfy the proposed divisibility pattern.  A 5-smooth number is a number with no prime factor greater than 5.

[Størmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%B8rmer%27s_theorem) has shown that there are only a finite number of consecutive 5-smooth numbers.  More on these kinds of questions [here](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath104/kmath104.htm).  [Pillai conjectured](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) that for fixed $A$, $B$, and $C$, $A x^n - B y^m = C$ has only a finite number of solutions $(x,y,m,n)$.  [Erick Wong](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/30402/erick-wong), in his answer to this problem, has demonstrated a reduction of the posted question to this form, such reduction being a (large-ish) list of such polynomials with exponent greater than three.  In fact, these are irreducible binary forms of degree three, so [Thue's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue_equation) applies and each has at most a finite number of solutions.  (Strictly, not all the forms on the raw list are irreducible, but this is no obstruction.)  Thue has shown that each equation has at most a finite number of solutions.  Wong's reduction thereby shows that there are a finite number of pairs of 5-smooth numbers that differ by less than 5.

**Update: 20140410**  Added extreme summary at the top.  The following paragraphs and code with results of PARI/GP solution of many Thue equations, replaces the subsequent paragraphs.

Rather than work through a reduction of the number of equations, we use very fast code in PARI-GP (2.7.0) to solve the problem quickly.  The code

> ```
> { for (a2 = 0, 2,     
>     for (a3 = 0, 2, 
>       for (a5 = 0, 2, 
>         for (b2 = 0, 2, 
>           for (b3 = 0, 2, 
>             for (b5 = 0, 2, 
>               ti = thueinit(2^a2*3^a3*5^a5*x^3 - 2^b2*3^b3*5^b5, 1);
>               for (d = 1, 4, 
>                 str = Strprintf("[% d, % d, % d] :  % s ", 
>                   2^a2*3^a3*5^a5, 2^b2*3^b3*5^b5, d, thue (ti, d));
>                 print (str);
>                 write ("some-output-file.txt", str);
>  ) )))))) }
> ```

solves the Thue equations we are interested in in a few seconds.  (Note that by default, the [thueinit](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html.stable/)() function sets up internal state to search for solutions assuming the generalized RH.  We have given the option to not make this optimistic assumption.  Consequently, the set of solutions found is unconditionally exhaustive.)  Of the 2916 equations, only 304 have solutions and the union of those sets contains 334 pairs (not all distinct).  Examples (ordered pairs are $(x,y)$):  $$ 1 x^3 - 1 y^3 = 1 : \{(0,-1),(1,0)\} $$
$$ 1 x^3 - 3 y^3 = 3 : \{(0,-1),(3,2)\} $$  The pairs of nearby 5-smooth integers produced by these solutions are frequently repeated.  Collecting pairs, sorting, and ignoring negative integers, the many equations give the following set of candidates (some of which are spurious):

$\{ (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5), (2,6), (3,4), (3,5), (3,6), (4,5), (4,6), (4,8), (5,6), (5,8), (5,9), (6,8), (6,9), (6,10), (8,9), (8,10), (8,12), (9,10), (9,12), (10,12), (12,15), (12,16), (15,16), (15,18), (16,18), (16,20), (18,20), (20,24), (24,25), (24,27), (25,27), (27,30), (30,32), (32,36), (36,40), (45,48), (48,50), (50,54), (60,64), (72,75), (80,81), (96,100), (125,128), (160,162), (240,243), (320,324), (6859,6860), (13718,13720), (20577,20580), (27436,27440) \}$

Except for the last four pairs, this agrees with the previous list (see below) which was generated by brute force calculation of 5-smooth numbers with exponents less than 200.  The last four pairs are spurious solutions because $6859=19^3$, $6860=2^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7^3$ and the subsequent three pairs are this pair multiplied by $2$, $3$, and $4$.  (Interestingly, only 7 and 19 appear as spurious factors in any of the solutions generated by the mass of polynomials.)

The PARI-GP code's output was parsed by the Mathematica 9.0 code

> ```
> Module[{ inFile,   lines, nonempty, instances  },
>   inFile = StringSplit[ Import["some-output-file.txt"], "\n" ];
>   lines = ToExpression[ StringReplace[
>      "{" <> # <> "}", {"[" -> "{", "]" -> "}", ":" -> ","}]] & /@ inFile;
>   Print["Total equations: ", Length[lines]];
>
>   nonempty = Select[lines, #[[2]] =!= {} &];
>   Print["Satisfiable equations: ", Length[nonempty]];
>
>   (* Switch from equation indexed to per-solution lists. *)
>   Print["Total solutions: ", Length[Flatten[nonempty[[All, 2]], 1]]];
>
>   instances[{eqn_, pairs_}] := 
>      {eqn[[1]]*#[[1]]^3, eqn[[2]]*#[[2]]^3} & /@ pairs;
>
>   Select[Split[Sort[
>      Sort /@ Flatten[instances /@ nonempty, 1]
>      ]][[All, 1]],
>      #[[1]] > 0 &
>   ]
> ]
> ```

generating only mildly syntactically different output from that listed above.

We therefore ...

- ... know there are only a finite number of solutions to the exponential Diophantine equations which are satisfied by counterexamples to the 5-consecutive 5-smooth numbers problem.
- ... have generated the complete set of solutions of polynomial relaxations to the exponential equations.  This introduced only a handful of spurious solutions.
- ... have eliminated the spurious solutions.
- ... showed the complete solution set is that found by previous direct (but not provably complete) generation of small 5-smooth integers.

**Discarded 20140410 starts here**:
Unfortunately, although we can show that each item in the list of equations has at most a finite number of solutions, part of the general solution method boils down to laboriously checking which of some set of potential solutions are actual solutions.  The bounds on the sizes of these sets are rather large, so this becomes impractical even for modest sizes of the coefficients.  Just $45x^n - y^n = 1$ is not easily disposed (in Mathematica 9.0).  The equations with coefficients $>100$, e.g., $900x^n - y^n = 4$, are likely infeasible at present.

A few small 5-smooth number pairs that differ by less than 5, skipping the near continuum up to 27: {27,30}, {30,32}, {32,36}, {36,40}, {45,48}, {48,50}, {50,54}, {60,64}, {72,75}, {80, 81}, {96,100}, {125, 128}, {160, 162}, {240, 243}, {320, 324}.  There may be more pairs.  There might not.  (There is no other with powers of 2, 3, and 5 less than 200.)

**Edit 20140326:**  Removed the first, wrong, sentence, "The question of even whether $2^m - 3^n = 5$ only finitely many times, a specialization of the generalized Tijdeman's conjecture, is still open.", and the rest of the first paragraph, largely replacing it with the second paragraph, above.  [Tijdeman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tijdeman%27s_theorem) has shown that the quoted sentence is false and Erick Wong was right to insist that this is the case.

Comment: Sorry, no, your first claim is quite false.  The finiteness of solutions to $2^m-3^n = d$ is well-established, as is the  divergence (to $\infty$) of gaps between $r$-smooth numbers for any fixed $r$.  Your own link cites a result of Tijdeman that $|2^m - 3^n| > 2^m/m^c$ for an absolute $c$, showing that the RHS tends to infinity quite rapidly.  There's a bit of recent discussion here with a reference: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716514/gap-between-smooth-integers-tends-to-infinity-stoermer-type-result

Comment: In retrospect, I shouldn't have downvoted this answer as overall it provides quite a lot of useful information, and even the OEIS entry http://oeis.org/A219794 gives the impression that this problem is open.

Comment: @ErickWong:  The question of number of solutions with *fixed* RHS is still open (unless the choice of RHS leads to a congruential contradiction).  With "sufficiently large" RHS, is resolved by Tijdeman.  The divergence of the *sup* of $r$-smooth gaps is known, but this question concerns the *inf*.

Comment: I disagree with the openness of the problem, but I am open to the possibility that I missed something.  I'll post an answer later today (either here or in the thread I referred to in my first comment) to expand on my claim for verification.

Comment: Okay, posted.  Does this change your mind about the number of solutions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "sufficiently large RHS".  Fix any RHS $d$ of $2^m - 3^n = d$.  Since $|2^m-3^n| \to \infty$ as $m$ increases, we have $|2^m-3^n| > |d|$ for all $m$ sufficiently large.  Hence there are only finitely many $m$ that satisfy $2^m-3^n = d$.

Comment: @ErickWong:  You have shown finite solution set for each simultaneously fixed $d$ and $n$.  Counting solutions doesn't work this way.  $a^m-b^n=k > 2$: Shorey, Tijdeman [1986]: open, conjectured finite; Pillai [1936]: fix $k$ sufficiently large, at most single solution.

Comment: To be clear, I am addressing your very first claim: "The question of even whether $2^m−3^n=5$ only finitely many times [...] is still open."  The 1986 conjecture you cite is likely for finiteness over all $a,b,m,n$ simultaneously, or perhaps a uniform bound independent of $a,b$.  When you fix $a=2,b=3$ this is far easier, as I have already shown (without fixing $n$).  I am unfamiliar with the precise statement of 1936 Pillai, but please note that "at most single solution" is a far stronger requirement than "finitely many solutions".

Comment: @ErickWong:  Arg.  I see what error in memory I have made.  Meh.  Editing...

Comment: I'm not an expert on Thue solving but I did attend a lecture by Bennett on this, and if I recall correctly the exponential size of the bounds can be overcome (I don't remember if continued fraction convergents come into play, but something of that sort would allow one to only consider a logarithmically small number of cases).  Pari/GP was able to solve both $45x^3 - y^3 = 1$ and $900x^3 - y^3 = 4$ instantaneously.

Comment: @ErickWong:  Well, I'm at about 60 hours on $x^n - 45 y^n = 1$ in M'ma 9.  Maybe it's time to learn Pari/GP.  At least I've reduced the list to about 200 equations based on simple divisibility arguments.  (I haven't looked for non-simple arguments.)

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive write-up!  I have only one upvote to give, but it deserves much more.

Answer (score 3):

If you unravel the definitions, you'll find as Eric Towers said that this is really about the minimum gap between $r$-smooth (aka friable) numbers.  This other recent [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716514/gap-between-smooth-integers-tends-to-infinity-stoermer-type-result) cites a survey of Tijdeman ([link](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1978.1/Main/icm1978.1.0381.0388.ocr.pdf)) containing a relevant excerpt:

> ...and in 1945 by Skolem to give an algorithm for determining all
>   solutions of certain equations of the form $a_1^{m_1} \cdots a_k^{m_k} -  b_1^{n_1} \cdots b_l^{n_l}= c$ in positive integers $m_1,\ldots,m_k,n_1,\ldots,n_l$ where
>   $a_1,\ldots,a_k,b_1,\ldots,b_l,c$ are given positive integers. The finiteness
>   of the number of solutions had been proved by Pólya in 1918 who
>   applied a third type of methods.

One minor quibble is that he says "positive integers" rather than nonnegative, but this could be adjusted by inflating the sets $\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}$ and $\{b_1,\ldots,b_l\}$ and multiplying $c$ by a constant.

Let me take this opportunity to give a fuller justification of the specific claim in this question, with a few pointers that should help OP narrow down the exact value.  Namely, for any $d \ne 0$ there are only *finitely* many solutions to $2^{m_1} 3^{m_2} 5^{m_3} - 2^{n_1} 3^{n_2} 5^{n_3} = d$.  Applying this to $d=1,2,3,4$, this means that all sufficiently large $5$-friable numbers must be at least $5$ apart, which I believe directly answers the original question.

The key tool is [Thue's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue_equation) which replaces the role of Pell equations in the proof of Størmer's theorem, combined with the "dumb trick" I mentioned in the other thread.  Let $S$ be the finite set $\{2^a 3^b 5^c: 0\le a,b,c \le 2\}$ of $27$ elements.  Then every solution to $2^{m_1} 3^{m_2} 5^{m_3} - 2^{n_1} 3^{n_2} 5^{n_3} = d$ is also a solution to $r x^3 - s y^3 = d$ for some $r,s \in S$ (where $rx^3 = 2^{m_1} 3^{m_2} 5^{m_3}$ and $sy^3 = 2^{n_1} 3^{n_2} 5^{n_3}$).

So it suffices to show that $rx^3 - sy^3 = d$ has only finitely many solutions for a fixed $r,s \in S$ and $d \ne 0$.  By our choice of $S$, if $r \ne s$ then $r/s$ does not have a rational cube root, thus $rx^3-sy^3$ is irreducible (being of degree $3$ with no roots) and Thue's theorem gives us this.  If $r = s$, then this reduces to showing that $x^3 - y^3 = d$ has finitely many solutions, which is clear from the fact that $(x+1)^3 - x^3 \to \infty$ as $x$ increases.

Computationally, Thue's theorem is effective (so is the much easier bound in the previous sentence) and Pari/GP contains a Thue equation solver.  If you have a programming bent (or know someone who does), you could just churn through the $4\cdot 27^2$ (at most) possibilities to find the exact value of $y$ in your question.

Comment: Thanks, Erick.  I am a programmer.  This gives me a good incentive to deep dive into Thue.  Cheers.  :-)  I'll post the $y$ on this question when I have it.

Comment: The method of decomposing exponential equations into polynomial equations you demonstrate is not well circulated.  The openness of the problem of Pillia's equation is widely published up to a decade ago.  http://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/paper19.pdf Allow me to quote Tijdemann from your reference:  "I think with the present methods the effective solution of an exponential equation by Baker's method is nigh to hopeless, [...]"  Having search bounds of $e^{e^{e^{10}}}$ is not encouraging.  I have implemented the search you describe.  Using best estimates, $900x^3-y^3=1$ is intractable.

Comment: @EricTowers I appreciate your efforts, but you are mistaken on several points.  The idea of decomposing exponentials into polynomials is the very basis of Størmer's theorem, so I don't agree that it is poorly circulated.  The openness of Pillai cited in Bennett's paper is for the general case where the bases are *not* fixed, which I fully agree is open; he rightly cites 1918 Pólya for the case at hand.  A similar qualifier applies to the hopelessness you quoted from Tijdemann but curiously elided.

Comment: I don't find this decomposition method when I access a copy of Stormer.

Comment: Pari/GP solves $900x^3 - y^3 = 1$ in a small fraction of a second (using the slower mode which does not assume GRH).

Answer (score -1):

...no such $y$ exist. Suppose otherwise, and let $p>5$ be such a prime, then $p|x+i$ and $p|x+(i+1)$ for some i, $1<=i<5$, hence $p|(x+i+1)-(x+i)$ or $p|1$, a contradiction...

Comment: The question allows the possibility that the primes $>5$ dividing two different numbers of the sequence are distinct: like $7\mid x+1$, $11\mid x+2$, $13\mid x+3$ and so on.