# $2^x - 3^y = k$, help understanding wolfram alpha

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, wolfram-alpha

I've been trying to understand this equation

$$2^{x} - 3^{y} = k$$

Specifically, I'm looking for all integer solutions to x and y such that k is a positive integer with $y > 1$. I figured I'd try wolfram alpha.

I suspected it would give me a family of solutions, but...

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2%5Ex+-+3%5Ey+%3D+k%2C+k%3E%3D1%2C+x%3E%3D1%2C+y%3E%3D2

It's telling me that the solutions are
$$k=5, x = 5, y = 3$$
$$k=7, x = 4, y = 2$$

This particularly doesn't seem like it can be everything, especially if I say that $x = 2y$, then I have infinitely many solutions. Why is this all that wolfram alpha is telling me.

Can anyone help me interpret what's happening here and provide other resources to look at for further understanding?

Thanks!

Comment: I think WA is merely saying "here are some integer solutions I found," with no claim that the given list is exhaustive. As you have observed, there are certainly an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: Is there a way to get a more exhaustive list of solutions? Or a way to understand better when 3^y + 1 is a power of 2? I feel like there are patterns in here I'm missing.

Comment: That's not a function, as written. It is just an equation

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the clarification, I've gone back and fixed it

Comment: Given $x>y\log_2 3,$ there is always a $k.$ You'll get the smaller $k$ when $x/y$ is an even continued fraction for $\log_2 3.$

Comment: Possible values of $k$ are listed at https://oeis.org/A192110

Comment: @TinyTim It is well-established that $3^y+1$ is only a power of $2$ when $y=0,1$.  This follows easily from Mihailescu's theorem, though this specific case is much easier to prove.  In general there are only finitely many solutions for any fixed $k$, and in fact this is true is a much broader sense: see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/725149/30402.

Comment: So $8/5$ is such a continued fraction, giving $256-243=13.$ But it gets hard to get small values, because $x-y\log_2 3=r$ being small just means $2^x/3^y=2^r$ or $2^x-3^y=3^y(2^r-1).$ But if $x/y$ is the $n$th continued fraction,  then $r>\frac1{2(c_{n+1}+1)y},$ where $c_{j}$ are the continued fraction coefficients. You need $c_{n+1}$ very large compared to $y$ to get a small $k.$

Comment: You should use MathJax also in the title.

Comment: @jjagmath - thanks, I'll do that from now on, sorry for missing that

Comment: @Thomas Andrews, Erick Wong - Thank you both so much, you've given me something to go on. I don't grasp everything just yet, but I'll make sure I understand it. Thank you kindly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case people were not aware, in the case of the single exponential problem $a^{n}= t$, if there is a solution modulo all prime powers, then there is an integer solution. (A nice proof is given in Cojocaru and Murty's book "An introduction to sieve methods and their applications.")

Comment: Thank you, I'll see if I can find a copy!